# NoSuchElementException Issue

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, java.util.scanner

What I am trying to do is to create a while loop where a program menu is run from until the user inputs a valid response.

However the scanner instance I have created does not want to play ball and keeps throwing NoSuchElementExceptions no matter what I have tried.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu
{
    Menu()
    {
        isValid = false;
        uInput = 0;
    }

    public int mMain()
    {
        Scanner in2;

        do
        {           
            in2 = new Scanner(System.in); //For user input

            System.out.println("Please choose from the following options");
            System.out.println("1) Enter Employee Data");
            System.out.println("2) Look Up Employee Information");
            System.out.println("3) Employee Comparison");
            System.out.println("4) Quit");
            uInput = in2.nextInt(); //This is the line throwing the exception.

            if (uInput < 1 || uInput > 4)
            {
                System.out.println("Your choice was not valid, please choose another option.");
            }

            else
            {
                isValid = true;
                in2.close();
            }
        } while (!isValid);

       isValid = false; //reset for next time
       System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); //Clear screen

       return uInput;       
    }

    int uInput; //For user input
    String uInput2; //for bug fixing
    boolean isValid; //check for valid use input
}
```

And in case it is needed here is my main method:

```
public class prg420_w4_commission_program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
    //class references
    Processing proc = new Processing();
    Menu menu = new Menu();

    //Set up Variables
    int uInput; //For user input
    boolean uQuit = false; //set up program loop bool

    //Opening message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Employee Data Entry Creation program.  Please follow the on-screen prompts.");
    System.out.println("");

    proc.initEDatabase(); //initialize employee database


    while (!uQuit)
    {

        uInput = menu.mMain(); //call main menu

        //Check user input
        switch (uInput)
        {
            case 1:
                proc.addEDBEntry(); //add employee entries
                break;

            case 2:
                proc.findEmployee();
                break;

            case 3:
                proc.sortEDBase();
                break;

            case 4:
                uQuit = true;
                break;

            default:
                proc.addEDBEntry();
                break;                      
        }           
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you for using the Employee Data Entry Creation program.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you enter a valid integer?

Comment: First of all, do some defensive programming. Before checking for an input check if there IS an input by invoking the `nextInt()` method inside an if that checks for `in2.hasNextInt()`. How does the program respond after adding this check?

Comment: @LewsTherin I do not get a chance to, it errors out the second it hits that line.  Gamb, I already tried both of those and got the same result.  It's something in another part of my program just not sure where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in2.close();
```

closes the input stream, after the first successful scan, `stdin` is closed and each attempt to get anything from it with a `Scanner` causes a `NoSuchElementException` to be thrown.

Comment: commented out the close but that line still throws the exception.  I should note that as soon as the program hits it, it throws the exception; I do not get a chance to enter anything into the prompt.

Comment: Seems like something else in my program is causing it.  I isolated this section in my main and commented out everything else and it worked just fine.

Comment: Perhaps `proc.initEDatabase();` already closes `System.in`? Or even the constructor? Those are the only candidates I see before ´MMain` is called.

Comment: It was in the constructor.  I was unaware that if you close the scanner stream even a new instance in a different class will no longer work.

Comment: Yes, closing a `Scanner` closes the underlying source (if that is `Closeable`). `System.in` is one stream for the entire process, so that's the explanation.